# mount /dev/sdc1 /media works but fstab fails to mount

Tags: arch-linux, mount, fstab, automounting

I'm running archlinux and have an ext3 10Tb internal harddrive that is failing to mount on boot through the fstab entry. If I use `mount /dev/sdc1 /media`, the mount succeeds however attempting to do a `mount -a` gives the result

```
mount: /media: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

I used `df -Th` to confirm the filesystem and got

```
 /dev/sdc1      ext3      9.1T  3.8T  4.9T  44% /media
```

I ran `e2fsck` to check the disk and got this

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdc1
e2fsck 1.45.3 (14-Jul-2019)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/sdc1: 30662/305201152 files (50.0% non-contiguous), 1020563007/2441608704 blocks
```

Which as far as I understand is all pass.

The `fstab` entry at the moment is

```
UUID=239630fb-affe-4810-a3a1-6d7c7958af86   /media      ext3        permissions,defaults    0 0

#/dev/sdc1                  /media      autofs      permissions,defaults    0 0
```

I've tried ext3, auto, and autofs as the file system for both entries but neither seems to help.

Comment: Add your `/etc/fstab` to your question.

Comment: Are you sure about the UUID in `/etc/fstab`? Try changing that line to read `/dev/sdc1   /media   etx3   permissions,defaults   0   0`.

Comment: ext3, not etx3 - sorry! :(

Comment: I've never come across `permissions` as a valid option for `extN` filesystems, and a quick look through the man pages doesn't offer me anything exciting. Are you sure it's valid?

Comment: Can you mount the filesystem using just `mount /media` after boot?

Comment: It seems it was a problem with permissions in the fstab It might be it was leftover from the ntfs system that was there thanks @roaima .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `permissions` option in your `/etc/fstab` isn't valid for an `ext3` filesystem